# how to do smooth movement of sprites in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my cocos2d project I am moving sprites from left most corner to the right most corner using CCMoveBy action. here is the code

```
CCSprite* sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
    sprite1.position = ccp(100, 100);
    [self addChild:sprite1];
    [sprite1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:
[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:4 position:ccp(300, 0)],
[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0, 200)],
[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:4 position:ccp(-300, 0)],
[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0, -200)], nil]];
```

the sprite is not moving smoothly, instead it stuck sometimes while moving.
someone asked a similar question In cocos2d forum

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/ccactions-not-running-smoothly-specifically-ccmoveby-and-ccrotateby/

but In my game I am using action sequences at so many places and it would be too much to code every movement sequence by scheduling update or custom selectors.

Comment: is your FPS constant at 60 or does it go down when the sprite stops?

Comment: Sequencing moves has the tendency to stop the movement for one frame before the new move action starts to run. Other than that the move runs smoothly *provided* that your framerate is a steady 60 fps.

Comment: it is never steady, even when I create a new cocos2d project and run the hello world. it is randomly changing between 59.0 to 60.0 I thought that it is normal. I am using iOS 6.1 emulator

Answer (score 0):

i think you can achieve this by following code

MovingSprite.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface MovingSprite : CCSprite {
    float _vx;
    float _vy;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt;

@property (nonatomic, assign) float vx;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float vy;

@end
```

MovingSprite.m

```
#import "MovingSprite.h"

@implementation MovingSprite

@synthesize vx = _vx;
@synthesize vy = _vy;

-(void)update:(ccTime)dT
{
    self.vy -= (kGravity * dT); //optionally apply gravity
    self.position = ccp(self.position.x + (self.vx*dT), self.position.y + (self.vy*dT));
}
```

And add [self scheduleUpdate]; to the init method of your game layer. Then add an update method within the game layer where you call update for all moving sprites.